# Selecting data from SQL-SERVER2008 - vb6?

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm selecting a bunch of data from SQL-SERVER...

```
sSql = Select Fname, Lname, Mname, Dob from tblClients
```

So i run this in my application, check the recordcount and it shows as 1. I run the query in the SQL-SERVER and all the values are NULL. So basically what i'm trying to do is populate a flex grid with data, or hide it if there's none. SO in this case I keep seeing an empty flex grid, even though it should recognize that there are no data being pulled from the server.

Comment: "all the values are null", so, you are returning a record set with one row of all nulls, or are you returning an empty recordset? From memory there is some weirdness around vb6 rowcounts and you need to traverse the rowset to get an accurate number - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?89826-ADO-recordset-recordcount-1, although I'm not sure this helps you exactly

Comment: The issue with RecordCount is simply that you have to use the right kind of Recordset.  It has nothing to do with VB6 and everything to do with the many (and useful) options for configuring Recordsets in ADO.  The link given above is a hilarious example of the blind leading the deaf and dumb.

Comment: Which Flexgrid?  The old DAO/VB5 one or the more fully featured ADO/VB6 Hierarchical Flexgrid?  And how are you "populating" the grid?  Of course empty is empty and if you have no rows returned we're barking at the wind.

Comment: Hierarchial, the name of it is MSHFlexGrid. I populate it by Selecting data from the table
        Set Me.fgrdActivity.DataSource = rs
        .FormatString = "|ColumnName|<ColumnNames2"
        .ColWidth(0, 0) = 0           'Column label
        .ColWidth(1, 0) = 1800

Comment: @LordBaconPants I'm actually selecting data for one client so sSQL = Select Fname, Lname, Mname, Dob from tblClients where ID= " & g_selectedID. The entire row is NULL values.

Comment: @barry17: There's an [edit] link up above (below your question). It's much more useful to add your code to the question where it can be properly formatted rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the PK as one of the fields selected, it is likely that you actually have a record with null values in the four selected fields.  One of the issues in SQL Server is that the resultset display doesn't distinguish between this condition and an actual empty resultset.

Best practice for checking whether you have returned an empty recordset is to check BOF and EOF, so:

```
With myRS
    If .BOF and .EOF Then
        'Hide FlexGrid and exit
    End If
End With
```

If .EOF is false, then you have a record with four null values in it.  Best way to check this is include the PK in your selection criteria.  Then you'll see it in your FlexGrid.

Once you've done that, you'll want to evaluate how your process allows null values for these fields if it turns out that you have such, because it seems clear from your post that isn't something that you want to allow.